# How to remove namespace from multiple XML files using ssis?

Tags: xml, ssis, namespaces, task

Trying to remove namespace from multiple xml files. Importing xml files from a folder and trying to export transformed xml files into output folder.
I utilized for each loop container and xml task in ssis but not sure why it gives me error. Any stepwise process will be helpful. Thanks
Here are the step wise process i did with end result..
1.Three xml files-
[image]

using xml task can easily remove the namespace in one file as follows[image]

[image]

here I have file without namespace in output folder
[image]
To remove namespace from all three files I use for each loop container and configure by defining variables:
[image]
[image]
then variable mapping[image]
[![enter image description here][8]][8]

Then source connection manager and destination connection manager was configure and then run the package
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Example 1 xml
```

<AMOUNT_MONEY xmlns="http://www.somewhere.com/ABC" version="5.252">


<CURRENT_ADDRESS occupancy_status="RENT" occupancy_description="">
<FORMER_ADDRESS street_address_1="1234 CIRCLE LN" county="" />
</CURRENT_ADDRESS>


</AMOUNT_MONEY>

```
Example 2 xml
<AMOUNT_MONEY xmlns="http://www.somewhere.com/ABC" version="5.252">
  <NAMES>
    <BORROWER home_country="USA" work_phone="" d3p1:internal_borrower_id="fec5645fc4cgd982" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.somewhere.com/Intern">
      <CURRENT_ADDRESS occupancy_status="OWN" occupancy_description="">
        <FORMER_ADDRESS street_address_1="111 MAIN LN" county="" />
      </CURRENT_ADDRESS>
    </BORROWER>
  </NAMES>
</AMOUNT_MONEY>

Example 3 xml

<AMOUNT_MONEY xmlns="http://www.somewhere.com/ABC" version="5.252">
  <NAMES>
    <BORROWER home_country="CA" work_phone="" d3p1:internal_borrower_id="8fec53vfg982845bf" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.somewhere.com/Intern">
      <CURRENT_ADDRESS occupancy_status="RENTTOOWN" occupancy_description="">
        <FORMER_ADDRESS street_address_1="985 CHERRY ST" county="" />
      </CURRENT_ADDRESS>
    </BORROWER>
  </NAMES>
</AMOUNT_MONEY>
```

COMMENT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />
   <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need to share all the details. Your input XML file sample, XSLT (?!), SSIS design, exact error, etc.

Comment: Just attached the description, mock file and error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please share your XSLT.

Comment: I do not have XSLT. I found a script on that work well when use in secondoperand in xml task. That convert xml with namespace to xml without. I added the secondoperand script in the question as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the XSLT on my machine without any problem. It removes the namespaces as desired.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let's concentrate on the SSIS side.

The `User::FILEPATH` variable will contain a fully qualified path to the source XML file in the Foreach Loop Container. So you cannot concatenate it directly with the destination directory.

What you need to do is to fix the destination file connection expression as follows:

```
"c:\\destinationDirectory\\" + TOKEN(@[User::FILEPATH], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FILEPATH], "\\"))
```

Comment: HI Yitzak.  thanks a lot  appreciate your response. Have another quick question ! Instead of putting transformed files into DestinationDirectory, is there a way to directly feed these transformed xml into data flow task and then into xml source  (in data flow) to load them into sql tables. Appreciate

Comment: @Paper, one post for one question. Please create a new question.

Comment: posted as a new question. Thanks